# Stop malware from being executed by launchd

Tags: launchd, malware

I've got this program running on my computer, `/var/root/Library/Application Support/.SectionChannel.dp/SectionChanneldd`, which Norton has identified as the malware OSX.Malcol.  However, Norton has been thoroughly unhelpful in doing anything about it.  I've tried deleting the file as well as sending a `SIGKILL` to the running process.  However, it keeps restarting.

Digging further via Activity Monitor, I discovered that the parent process is `launchd`.  How can I figure out what is causing `launchd` to execute this program and stop it?  Resetting my computer does not fix the issue.

Running `launchctl list | grep Section` shows

```
5727  -9  com.help.SectionChanneld
-     0   com.SectionChannel.system
```

EDIT:

I ran `launchctl dumpstate` and searched for all of the .plist files associated with the malware.  I deleted those files, restarted my computer, and now everything appears to be fine.  However, is this sufficient?

Comment: You should have multiple lines of defense. Also look at the dates on the malware files to figure out which date you installed it, from which app/site/download, from which browser.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app Malwarebytes which is popular for detecting and deleting Malware. I don't know how this compares to Nortons but maybe its a viable option. The website,located here https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/,  advertises a free version.  The full application is available here: https://www.malwarebytes.com and also offeres a free version.

Comment: Malwarebytes on Mac is great and superior to Norton.